# Online server not recognizing changes to Node server.js file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx

I use `server.js` to make api calls. I have these calls working locally, but once I push to the main server, it's as though they don't exist.

Client-side, all my changes are properly updated, but no updates get recognized from my `server.js` file.

The weird thing is all the changes I made to server.js can be seen when I `vim` into `server.js` on my **server**. It's just that those changes aren't being transferred to the actual runtime of the server.

Before I push to the server, I first `sudo npm run build` in my local client directory, then I push the app folder.

I'm using `nginx` and `pm2`. I tried to restart both but no results.

I've tried on incognito, and clearing my browser's cache. It's not updating on other computers as well.

Comment: Sounds like `pm2` wasn't stopped and restarted

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. 
basically what was happening was node wasn’t stopping when I tried to `pm2 stop <id>`

So I rebooted the aws server and restarted pm2 and nginx and it worked